# SwipeRight using touchSwipe.js

Tags: jquery

I'm using the [touchSwipe](http://labs.rampinteractive.co.uk/touchSwipe/demos/) plugin for mobile side swiped motions. I'm having a bit of trouble though.

I can get the left swipe to work just fine.

```
$(".grid").swipe({
  swipeLeft:function(event, direction, distance, duration, fingerCount) {
     alert('swipe left');
  }
});
```

but for some odd reason I cannot get the right swipe to work and I'm not really seeing what I am doing wrong.

```
$(".grid").swipe({
  swipeRight:function(event, direction, distance, duration, fingerCount) {
    alert('swipe right');
  }
});
```

Can someone help me see what the heck I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try setting them both at the same time maybe?

```
$(".grid").swipe({
  swipeLeft:function(event, direction, distance, duration, fingerCount) {
     alert('swipe left');
  }, 
  swipeRight:function(event, direction, distance, duration, fingerCount) {
     alert('swipe right');
  }
});
```

Depending on order, you might be erasing the swipeRight when you set the swipeLeft like that.